# simple_form how to find out with capybara if form is valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, simple-form

Using capybara, I would like to assess if my `simple_form` is valid, i.e. if the previous submission was processed without errors.

Today, I am using :

```
expect(page).not_to have_selector(".field_with_errors")
```

Unfortunately, the **`not_to`** will need to wait for `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` to make sure the form does not contain any invalid input.

Is there a way I can configure **simple_form** so I can detect valid forms with a `expect(page).to` instead of `expect(page).not_to` ?

Comment: This is very smelly. Test the actual behavior instead for example by testing that you're redirected to the newly created resource or that the updated resource has the new attributes. One reason its so smelly is that the test will pass if you just change the markup of the page even through no resource is created.

Comment: I mean if you really want to cheat at integration testing just write `expect { do_the_thing }.to change(Thing, :count)` which isn't prone to false postives.

Comment: Where did get the understanding that `not_to` would wait the full time? Assuming Capybaras matchers have been correctly installed `not_to have_selector(..)` will behave the same as `to have_no_selector(…` which is to move on as soon as the element is not on the page

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ThomasWalpole . When using `to have_selector(...` I noticed in some cases I may have to increase the wait a little, because the expectation is not met right after the submission (especially with selenium). 
So **you are right** and `not_to` may actually not wait; but still it could return a false positive, because right after the start of submission, the form will still be "turbo-loading". How can I validate the resulting form is without any error ?

Comment: Thanks @max for your answer. Indeed this test alone is not sufficient. For testing the redirection and saving behavior, I am using controller specs. Here, I want to test my form, custom inputs, and user interactions. This test is the **happy path** among many others paths. 
I also agree with your first comment. I think the main reason why it's not robust is because of the `not_to` (which will pass even if the page is blank). Hence my question to turn the **not_to** into a **to**.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [documentation](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#custom-inputs) of simple form, gives the flexibility to add custom inputs which you can track in capybara while default_max_wait_time. Also this time can be reduced as well but i think that will not server the purpose here

use something like this `And in the SimpleForm initializer :

#config/simple_form.rb

```
config.custom_inputs_namespaces << "CustomInputs"`
or
SimpleForm.error_class = "field_with_errors" #valid form
```

Other wrapper which you can use as per gem readme

```
config.wrappers tag: :div, class: :input, 

                 error_class: :field_with_errors,
                 valid_class: :field_without_errors do |b|
```

Now expect(page).to should work as per the expectation